# Does camel use an implicit read lock for files?

Tags: java, apache-camel, readonly, jbossfuse, file-read

I'm consuming a file using **Camel File** component as follows:

```
<from uri="file:myDir?noop=true&amp;filter=myFilter&amp;scheduler=quartz2&amp;scheduler.cron={{schedule}}/>
```

The source location is read only. [Camel File documentation](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) says, it won't be using a read lock by default.

But, I'm getting a permission denied exception while running this code.

> Endpoint[file://myFile?filter=myFilter&idempotent=true&noop=true&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron={{mySchedule}}
>   cannot begin processing file: GenericFile[myDir\myFile] due to: Access
>   is denied. Caused by: [java.io.IOException - Access is denied]
>
> Stack Trace java.io.IOException: Permission denied   at
>   java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)[:1.8.0_66]
>   at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)[:1.8.0_66]   at
>   org.apache.camel.util.FileUtil.createNewFile(FileUtil.java:587)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621090
>   com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.MarkerFileExclusiveReadLockStrategy.acquireExclusiveReadLock(MarkerFileExclusiveReadLockStrategy.java:71)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621090
>   com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.begin(GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.java:49)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621090
>   com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.begin(GenericFileRenameProcessStrategy.java:35)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621090
>   com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:352)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621090
>   com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:211)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621090
>   com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621090
>   com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:174)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621090
>   com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:101)[org.apache.camel:camel-core:2.15.1.redhat-621090
>   com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4.2]
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.pollconsumer.quartz2.QuartzScheduledPollConsumerJob.execute(QuartzScheduledPollConsumerJob.java:59)[org.apache.camel:camel-quartz2:2.15.1.redhat-621090]
>   at
>   org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)[org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1]
>   at
>   org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)[org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1]

From the stack trace, it appears that, camel is trying to create a **readLock** and it is causing exception due to lack of of permission.

So, my questions are

- Why camel is using a lock, even if default value of read lock is **none**
- If this is expected behavior, how can I consume file from a read only location where I don't have write permission?

**UPDATE**

I tried setting `readLockMarkingFile` to `false` as suggested in one of the answer, but that did n't solve the problem. So, I explicitly set `readLock` to `none`. Now, it is working. Don't know, why `readLock` is not `none` by default as mentioned in documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The readLock-option only decides whether camel will try to acquire an exclusive read-lock on the file. There is another option called "readLockMarkerFile" which defaults to true, set that option to false and you should be fine.

```
<from uri="file:myDir?noop=true&amp;filter=myFilter&amp;scheduler=quartz2&amp;scheduler.cron={{schedule}}&amp;readLockMarkerFile=false/>
```

Comment: I tried setting readLockMarkerFile to false. But that did n't work. Then I tried explicitly setting readLock=none, that worked. It appears that, in this case, camel is using rename readLock, but I have no idea Why.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't directly answer your question, I've used a trigger file (0 bytes) which the file watcher looks for. Your route would then work on the actual file to which the trigger is a companion. The trigger file is moved to a subdirectory /parent/.camel so it doesn't process again. Although we have noticed routes try to 'pick up' the actual file in a distributed environment where there is more than one server running the route.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem, the documentation states that the default value of the parameter is `none`, but in fact `markerFile` is used. To resolve this, you must explicitly specify this parameter `readLock=none`(camel-version 2.20.2)